# How to ask for the outer class in IntelliJ's templating language?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, texttemplate

I found out how to change the default templates in IntelliJ when generating `toString` and `hashCode`/`equals` implementations but I cannot find any proper documentation on what variables are accessible. Autocomplete helps but it does not show me any such option.

Basically, I want to change the `toString` template to generate a prefix of `Foo.Bar` for the following inner class

```
class Foo {
  class Bar { }
}
```

where it now simply puts `Bar` without the prefix. I do **not** want to add the package name!

Bonus questions: How can I set the global parameters? I am also trying to change the parameter name of the `equals` template from `o` to `object`.

Answer (score 1):

A documentation on what variables are accessible within the template can be found here: [Documentation of the `toString` settings dialog](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/generate-tostring-settings-dialog.html).

Unfortunately, I cannot find anything variable like `class.hasOuterClass`, `class.outerClassName` or something similar.

After a little research I found an ugly solution but it works, if you class name start with a capital letter and your package names are all lower case.

Put the following at the beginning of your template:

`#set( $classname = $FQClassname.substring($StringUtil.indexOfAny($FQClassname, "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")))`

Bonus question:

I did not find a similar documentation for the `equals/hashCode` template but I looked at the source code of the [`equalsHelper.vm`](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/java/java-impl/src/com/intellij/codeInsight/generation/equalsHelper.vm) on GitHub.

If you put `#set( $baseParamName = "object" )` before the `#parse("equalsHelper.vm")` the `$paramName` will then be named `object` if there will be no other local variable with that name. This happens, if you have a member variable with that name.

[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you a lot. The thing with the renaming of *o* to *object* did work but I had to put the statement after the *parse* statement. At the same time, Velocity does not accept the string manipulation for the `toString` method. Instead, it emits an error.

Comment: The `$classname` overriding work for me. What's the error message, which idea version are you using and which template did you use?